# change color by calling name

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

Update: Not sure if this code would work, but couldn't get the name of the sprite where `c.getChildByName(spName)` is null, `spName` is the string name of the sprite.

```
 private var s:Sprite;
                private var s2:Sprite;
    private var c:UIComponent;
                private var c2:UIComponent;

                private function drawQuarterNotes(xx:int,ty:String):void {
                    if(ty=="up") {
                        s = new Sprite();
                        s2 = new Sprite();

                        c = new UIComponent();
                        c2 = new UIComponent();

                        s2.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x333333);
                        s2.graphics.moveTo(20,0);
                        s2.graphics.lineTo(20,50);
                        c2.addChild(s2);
                        c2.x = xx+16;
                        c2.y = xx-18;

                        s.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
                        s.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
                        s.graphics.endFill();
                        s.name = "asd2";
                        s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,chgColor);
                        s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,chgColorReset);
                        c.addChild(s);
                        c.rotation = -20;
                        c.x = xx;
                        c.y = xx;
                    }
                    if(ty=="down") {
                        s2.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x333333);
                        s2.graphics.moveTo(20,0);
                        s2.graphics.lineTo(20,50);
                        c2.addChild(s2);
                        c2.x = xx+1;
                        c2.y = xx+35;

                        s.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
                        s.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
                        s.graphics.endFill();
                        c.addChild(s);
                        c.rotation = -20;
                        c.x = xx;


c.y = xx;                   
                }
                addElement(c);
                addElement(c2);
            }

            private function drawQuarterNotes2(xx:int,ty:String):void {
                if(ty=="up") {
                    s = new Sprite();
                    s2 = new Sprite();

                    c = new UIComponent();
                    c2 = new UIComponent();

                    s2.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x333333);
                    s2.graphics.moveTo(20,0);
                    s2.graphics.lineTo(20,50);
                    c2.addChild(s2);
                    c2.x = xx+16;
                    c2.y = xx-18;

                    s.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
                    s.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
                    s.graphics.endFill();
                    s.name = "asd1";
                    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,chgColor);
                    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,chgColorReset);
                    c.addChild(s);
                    c.rotation = -20;
                    c.x = xx;
                    c.y = xx;
                }
                if(ty=="down") {
                    s2.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x333333);
                    s2.graphics.moveTo(20,0);
                    s2.graphics.lineTo(20,50);
                    c2.addChild(s2);
                    c2.x = xx+1;
                    c2.y = xx+35;

                    s.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
                    s.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
                    s.graphics.endFill();
                    c.addChild(s);
                    c.rotation = -20;
                    c.x = xx;
                    c.y = xx;                   
                }
                addElement(c);
                addElement(c2);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private var c:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    private var s1:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var s2:Sprite = new Sprite();

    private function init():void
    {
       s1.name = "shape1";
       s2.name = "shape2";

       //make sure s2 doesn't appear on top of s1
       s2.x = 100;

       s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,  chgColorBlue);
       s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,    chgColorReset);

       c.addChild(s1);
       c.addChild(s2);
       addElement(c);

       //change shape1 to red
       changeSpriteColor( 'shape1' , 0x990000 );

       //change shape2 to grey
       changeSpriteColor( 'shape2' , 0x777777 );
    }

    //change a sprite color by calling its name
    private function changeSpriteColor( spName:String , color:uint ):void
    {
        var child:Sprite = c.getChildByName(spName ) as Sprite;

        //make sure the child has been added to the container
        if( child != null )
           shapeGraphics( child , color );
    }

    //change a sprite color
    private function shapeGraphics( sp:Sprite  , color:uint ):void
    {
       //make sure to clear the graphics , before changing the color
       //there are other ways to change the color
       //but i'm following your code!
       sp.graphics.clear();
       sp.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
       sp.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
       sp.graphics.endFill();  
    }

    private function chgColorBlue(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
       shapeGraphics( e.currentTarget , 0x000099 );
    }

    private function chgColorReset(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
       shapeGraphics( e.currentTarget , 0x333333 );
    }
```

Comment: That cool and more easier! But I have a problem if I have implement multiple instance the only newest sprite can be recognise, the old ones would be lost, mean could not call their names, how do I retains all of them so I can change individually?

Comment: you're not losing anything! from the moment you create a new instance of a Sprite, give it a name & add it to the container , you will be able to change its color by using the changeSpriteColor method. you will only lose a Sprite reference if it is removed from the container & isn't assigned to a variable outside the scope of the function where you created it.

Comment: Follow your code, the UIComponent and Sprite are declares as global, when I ran two functions which will create "shape1" and "shape2", the "shape1" is disappear on stage but shape2 remain.

Comment: I have update my code and see if this is the correct way of coding with 2 musical notes. Suppose if one is quarter note name "asd2" and the other is asd1, I feel confuse why it can't seem to work with many combination.

Comment: oh, so we have to create as many sprites for each graphic? It cannot be shared? If it is, I have a better understanding now. Left one thing is to create new sprite as a variable. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're writing this function in the `actions` of the flash file, and not in a separate `.as` file. This function will rely on the `stage` object being set (if you were to port this to a class, you may or may not have to wait for the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event.)

```
function chgColorBlue():void
{
  var element = stage.getChildByName('shape1');
  element.graphics.beginFill(0x000099);
  element.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
  element.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Edit to show example:
You can call this function after creating the object. It defeats the purpose of trying to access the element by the name attribute.

```
function chgColorBlue(element:Sprite):void
{
  element.graphics.beginFill(0x000099);
  element.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
  element.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: Erm, I am using Flash builder, still getting after trying your code "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Comment: I would get null from the trace but adding .name after "shape1" also doesn't work.

Comment: A fix may just be to pass the element as a parameter to the function and drop the `var element = stage.getChildByName('shape1');` line. The function declaration would then be `function chgColorBlue(element:Sprite):void`.  I'm guess you're either not calling the function **after** the element has been created, or you're not adding the element to the stage directly and need to call `getChildByName` in the context of a different element.

Comment: How does it look like? Could you mind give me an example? Out for lunch now.